# Header text was changed when post back

Tags: asp.net

I am facing a issue when i'm working with telerik control
[image]

When I click expand in parent row, it'll show child with two links View Error and View History
and default history grid will show 
When I expand link view Error that will show error grid with header text is Error 
I only use a grid that contains data history or error and I change name header text corresponding with type 
Assume Faculity 1 I click view error , my grid will show with header text Error
But when I click any action in grid such as expand row at faculity 2 , header text in grid at row Faculity 1 will rechange "History" although data in grid not change (still error data)
Can you show me how to fix that issue , thank you so much !